# Is this a valid interpretation of the mean relative speed/collision rate of particles in a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, collision, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory

In textbooks, the collision frequency $Z_{ab}$ between two species "a" and "b" is always given as something like:

$$Z_{ab} = n_an_b\sigma_{ab} \Bigg(\frac{8 k T}{\pi \mu}\Bigg)^{1/2}= n_an_b\sigma_{ab} \bar{C}_{rel}$$

where $n_a$ and $n_b$ are the number density of species a and b respectively, $\sigma$ is the collision cross-section, and the reduced mass $\mu = m_am_b/(m_a+m_b)$. Given that the mean speed of a species "i" is given by $\bar{C}_i = \Big(\frac{8 k T}{\pi m_i}\Big)^{1/2}$, then, algebraically,  the first equation is equivalent to:

$$Z_{ab} = n_an_b\sigma_{ab} \sqrt{\bar{C}_a^2 + \bar{C}_b^2}$$

Is there a reason that this is not a valid interpretation of the collision frequency? I have not found a single source which presents either the collision rate $Z_{ab}$, or the mean relative speed $\bar{C}_{rel}$ in this way.

Comment: Although the following is for a plasma, the derivation starts from the same place:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023

Comment: Thanks, Thats the first time I've seen someone else refer to the mean speed of both species in this way!  My application is also plasma based, but far lower temperature than them.

Comment: Yes, the relevant speed is mean average thermal speed between the two species, for a statistical representation assuming Maxwellians.  I imagine this changes if the velocity distributions are not Maxwellians since the relevant speed changes.

Comment: @honeste_vivere , I just noticed you are the only person who commented on my other post as well. Thank you.